# Blind signal separation on mixed images using FastICA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, signal-processing

I have a grayscale image, which was obtained from a set of images randomly mixed. I would use the [FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) algorithm in order to retrieve the original images, but the number of original images is not known. How to deal with this problem? How to proceed after loading the image to be processed?

Comment: May be worth asking here instead - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ - but take a look at this first - http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1929170

Comment: FastICA on its own probably won't do the trick because you need an algorithm that will **jointly** estimate the number of sources and the mixture coefficients. If I recall correctly, the "LOST" algorithm does this pretty well for **instantaneous** (non-convolutive) speech mixtures and is very simple and rather similar to FastICA. Unfortunately I don't know any for image processing, but this might be a good starting point.